# Creating a function in NodeJS that returns a query result as a call back?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to verify proper database operation using mocha/chai in NodeJS. I'm trying to create a way to run a sql query and then verify that it properly executed. Right now I am doing all the mysql execution in order but when I get to the assertion the result hasn't been generated yet, so I was wondering the best solution to this problem?

Here is the way I have it currently set up but when the expect() statement runs the array doesn't have data in it yet.

```js
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const mysql = require('mysql');

describe('Test mysql credentials, connection and CRUD  operation', function() {
  var host = "localhost";
  var user = "user";
  var pass = "pass";

  describe('Test CREATE DATABASE', function() {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: host,
      user: user,
      password: pass
    });
    before(function(done) {
      connection.query("CREATE DATABASE test_db;", function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      done();
    });

    it('Database Sucessfully Created', function() {
      var databases = new Array();
      connection.query("SHOW DATABASES;", function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          databases.push(result[i].Database);
        }
      });
      expect(databases).to.include('test_db');
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query is asynchronous, you need to set the `expect` in the callback function. You also have to call the `done` function once the assertion is executed.

```
it('Database Sucessfully Created', function(done) {
  var databases = new Array();
  connection.query("SHOW DATABASES;", function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      databases.push(result[i].Database);
    }

    expect(databases).to.include('test_db');
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code. You can also return a Promise if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to of fixed the problem. So is the function(err, result) in the query function essentially a built in callback?

Comment: What do you mean by built in callback?

Comment: I apologize if i'm being confusing. I guess I mean does the internal operations (ex the for loop or error catch) of the connection.query function wait to execute until the mysql query returns either an error or a result?

Comment: The `connection.query` function will be executed and once it finishes, or if it encounters an error, it will call the callback that you provided. This is an easy way to deal with asynchrony.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the help!